# Autowiring Spring services into JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4, spring-junit

Following is the service.

```
@Service
public class MyService  {
   public List<Integer> getIds(Filter filter){
      // Method body
   }
}
```

And a configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public static class MyApplicationContext {

    @Bean
    public Filter filter(ApplicationContext context) {
        return new Filter();
    }
}
```

The desired goal is a unit test to confirm **getIds()** returns the correct result.
See the JUnit test below.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyApplicationContext.class,                                                   
                      loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class AppTest
{
    @Autowired
    Filter filter;

    @Autowired
    MyService service;
}
```

The compiler finds the correct bean for the Filter class but throws a `BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field` exception for the service variable. I've tried adding the service class to the ContextConfiguration classes attribute but that results in a `IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` exception.

How can I add MyService to ContextConfiguration?

Comment: paste full stack trace please? And have you defined any beans in xml as well would help (if any)

Comment: You have to [tell spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) to scan for `@Service` annotations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following annotation to `MyApplicationContext` for the service to be scanned `@ComponentScan("myservice.package.name")`

Answer (score 3):

Add these two annotations to the test class AppTest, like in the following example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest
public class ProtocolTransactionServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProtocolTransactionService protocolTransactionService;
}
```

`@SpringBootTest` loads the whole context.